# aggregate query performance sorting by ISODate

Tags: mongodb, database-performance, isodate

I have this kind of simple aggregate query

```
db.SomeCollection.aggregate([{
  "$match": {
    "Id": "someId"
  }
}, {
  "$sort": {
    "someISODatePropertyName": 1
  }
}, {
  "$unwind": {
    "path": "$somePropertyName"
  }
}], {
  allowDiskUse: true
})
```

this query returns 50 items at most and takes 10 seconds to complete.

If I simply change the sort property with a numeric one:

```
db.SomeCollection.aggregate([{
  "$match": {
    "Id": "someId"
  }
}, {
  "$sort": {
    "someNumericPropertyName": 1
  }
}, {
  "$unwind": {
    "path": "$somePropertyName"
  }
}], {
  allowDiskUse: true
})
```

the query takes a few milliseconds to complete.

Is there any sorting issue with ISODate properties?

I really can't understand why it takes so long in the first version.

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

this is the query result with "explain" flag set to true (note: on the ISODate field there is an index):

```
{
    "waitedMS" : NumberLong(0),
    "stages" : [ 
        {
            "$cursor" : {
                "query" : {
                    "StreamId" : "5b8cc895-c626-5994-95d4-b9ac89fb66ed"
                },
                "sort" : {
                    "CommitStamp" : 1
                },
                "queryPlanner" : {
                    "plannerVersion" : 1,
                    "namespace" : "vrp-events-prod.Commits",
                    "indexFilterSet" : false,
                    "parsedQuery" : {
                        "StreamId" : {
                            "$eq" : "5b8cc895-c626-5994-95d4-b9ac89fb66ed"
                        }
                    },
                    "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                        "filter" : {
                            "StreamId" : {
                                "$eq" : "5b8cc895-c626-5994-95d4-b9ac89fb66ed"
                            }
                        },
                        "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "CommitStamp" : 1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "CommitStamp_Index",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 1,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "CommitStamp" : [ 
                                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "rejectedPlans" : []
                }
            }
        }, 
        {
            "$unwind" : {
                "path" : "$Events"
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience date sorting without an index on the date field is slow. Assuming that you read from this collection often and usually sort by date, adding an index will be the ideal solution.

db.collection.createIndex("someISODatePropertyName": 1 or -1)

Try it, it always made a huge difference for me.

**Update:**

Assuming that this doesn't slow down your write queries too much, add an index that covers both the match and the sort:

db.xxx.createIndex({"StreamId": 1, "CommitStamp": 1});

I tested this on my collection and it sped up the query from 15 seconds (using the date index) to less than a second (using the newly created index). FYI, my updated explain shows:

```
"queryPlanner" : {
                                        "plannerVersion" : 1,
                                        "namespace" : "db.xxx",
                                        "indexFilterSet" : false,
                                        "parsedQuery" : {
                                                "id" : {
                                                        "$eq" : 122
                                                }
                                        },
                                        "winningPlan" : {
                                                "stage" : "FETCH",
                                                "inputStage" : {
                                                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                                        "keyPattern" : {
                                                                "id" : 1,
                                                                "date" : 1
                                                        },
                                                        "indexName" : "id_1_date_1",
                                                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                                                        "direction" : "forward",
                                                        "indexBounds" : {
                                                                "id" : [
                                                                        "[122.0, 122.0]"
                                                                ],
                                                                "date" : [
                                                                        "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                                                ]
                                                        }
                                                }
                                        },
                                        "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
                                }
```

Comment: yes, I forgot to mention that I already have an index on that field (and btw not on the numeric...)
what I find so strange is the dramatic performance difference between a numeric field and a date field during a simple sort operation

Comment: I'm thinking about the solution. I'm surprised that the index is not sufficient. Can you try to run your queries with explain as an option and see what it says?
https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/

Comment: Thanks,
I updated the post with the explain query result.

Comment: I was also looking for values like: totalDocsExamined to see if the index had to examine a lot of documents. Why don't we try to write a covered query, which would require examining 0 documents. Remove the index on date and write an index on id, then date, and see if it is possible. I am going to test with this today and get back to you (I'm in California, it's 6am)

Comment: I have updated my answer. Basically, your index needs to also cover the match for StreamId. I hope that works! But if you are adding a lot of documents to that collection, make sure that your writes don't take too long now.